# Conditional define to suppress IDE interception of Exceptions in Delphi 6 Pro?

Tags: delphi, exception, conditional-statements, access-violation

I know I can use the IDE settings in Delphi Pro 6 to stop the IDE from intercepting and handling Delphi Exceptions (stopping the program and entering Debug mode), but unfortunately that turns off that handling for all Exceptions.  The Access Violation Exception is happening in a DLL that I don't have the source code for.  I was wondering if there is a conditional symbol I don't know about that I could define/undefine around the offending code block so at least I could turn off Exception handling around that code block.  If not, perhaps some trick or technique to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compiler directives control how the compiler and linker turn your source code into executable code. Debugging instructions aren't stored in the DCU or the binary, so compiler directives can't control what you're after.

There are several ways to control exception handling. I've described them in [an article I wrote a few years ago](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exception-messages):

- Use "advanced breakpoints" to define where the debugger should start or stop interrupting on exceptions.
- Define certain exception classes that the debugger will always ignore.
- Disable stopping on exceptions.
- Disable debugging altogether.

Comment: Please update your answer because the article you wroted seems to be offline.