# Delphi 2007 - programmatic manipulation of the "exceptions to ignore" list

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-2007, integer-overflow

I have an application which occasionally returns an integer overflow when `FormatDateTime` is called.  I have no idea what scenario triggers this, although I have found mention of the problem [here](http://forums.zuggsoft.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=35781) and [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_21926194.html).

My current workaround is to wrap the function and handle the exception:

```
function FormatDateTimeEx (const FormatString : ANSIString ;
                                 DateTime     : TDateTime) : ANSIString ;
begin
try
    Result := FormatDateTime (FormatString, DateTime) ;
except
    Result := '???' ; 
    end ;
end ;
```

which solves the issue of this problem causing the compiled executable to crash, but I would also prefer it if the debugger did not break on the `EIntOverflow` exception when I an running the program in the IDE.  I don't want to do this by telling the IDE to ignore the `EIntOverflow` exception, because then it won't break on other occasions when an untrapped integer overflow occurs (right?).

Is there a programmatic way (compile-time or run-time) of telling the IDE to locally ignore an exception class, for those occasions when an exception can occur, and you already know that and are handling it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to understand the actual problem and apply a real fix?

Comment: I think this asked for the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271066/conditional-define-to-suppress-ide-interception-of-exceptions-in-delphi-6-pro

Comment: @David, sure it would, but in this case I'm pretty sure the problem is  in the VCL (and FormatDateTime is in assembler) or outside the building.  I also saw mention of occasions where calling `FormatDateTime` caused an access violation, so I wouldn't be certain that applying a fix - which I would have thought could only be done by determining the combinations and values of parameters which triggered the exception and filtering them out - would work in all cases.

Comment: @TLama, yep, didn't pick that up in my initial trawl.  I'll read Robs article.

Comment: I'm sure that if you supplied SSCCE, we could supply fix

Comment: The problem is seemingly date-sensitive - it was observed this morning, but it's not happening now.  I could write a SSCCE that threw random dates at the function I suppose, but I suspect that it is maybe senstive to the current datetime and timezone also.

Comment: Just a guess: [`FormatDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) you use is **not** thread-safe. Try to use the thread-safe version in the whole application

Comment: Call is from main VCL thread

Comment: That does not matter, it just matters if there are two concurrent calls from different threads at the same time and it seems to be so

Comment: @SirRufo, the problem might be in a "wrong" input date time value as well; e.g. this leads to a division by 0 exception `FormatDateTime('', 10000000000);` just because `TDateTime` type is so unsafe.

Comment: @SirRufo Isn't the lack of thread safety due to the use of a shared global format variable?

Comment: Well, I have an idea. For this particular issue your wrapper seems good. I created a similar one when I got to catch one tricky Format error (I added logging the FormatString so that I could detect the place where it was happening). So all that you have to add is: `on E: EIntOverflow do begin if not IsDebuggerPresent then raise; end else raise`. So you'll have all Format exceptions pass through, and EIntOverflow would be silenced only for FormatDateTime and only when running under IDE.

Comment: @Fr0sT I'm not following you.  This fragment would be added to the except part of my wrapper routine's `try..except`, right?  What happens when I am running under the debugger and an `EIntOverflow` happens somewhere else in my program?

Comment: @rossmcm, yes, right. Exception would be cought for the FormatDateTime call only, and only under debugger. Exception happened in other places won't be touched and will be raised as usual.

Comment: @Fr0sT So what do I have the IDE setting "Notify on language exceptions" set to?  And do I include EIntOverflow in the list of exception types to ignore?  I still don't see how EIntOverflow can still trigger the IDE exception handling in other places in the program and not fire in FormatDateTimeEx.

Comment: @rossmcm, oops. Debugger indeed reacts on the exception regardless the presence of try-except section in the code. Sorry for confusing, I never use "Stop on exception" option so I forgot the way it works. I'm afraid it's impossible to do what you want. The only option I see now is to investigate what exactly values cause exception and filter them before formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a programmatic way (compile-time or run-time) of telling the IDE to locally ignore an exception class, for those occasions when an exception can occur, and you already know that and are handling it?

Not in code, no.  However, it can be done in the debugger using Breakpoints.

Wrap the affected code with two Breakpoints:

```
function FormatDateTimeEx(const FormatString: AnsiString; DateTime: TDateTime): AnsiString;
begin // <-- breakpoint
  try
    Result := FormatDateTime (FormatString, DateTime) ;
  except
    Result := '???'; 
  end;
end; // <-- breakpoint
```

Go into the Properties of the first Breakpoint and enable the **Ignore subsequent exceptions** option and disable the **Break** option.

Go into the Properties of the second Breakpoint and enable the **Handle subsequent exceptions** option and disable the **Break** option.

Comment: Thanks Remy,  I found that solution exactly in [this post](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exception-messages).  For some reason I still get entries in the IDE event log each time the breakpoints are passed by.  This seems to result in the message loop firing which is causing other side effects in the application.  I can't find where you might suppress these event log entries.

Comment: You cannot disable the EventLog messages when a breakpoint is hit, only control how the breakpoint behaves.  But a breakpoint that does not `break` should not be triggering events in your app's message loop.

Comment: I think I see what is going on.  It seems to be connected with a timer event firing and then firing again before the first timer event handling has finished.  This only happens when there is the extra delay involved in logging the two events.

code smell.

Comment: If you are using `TTimer` then its event cannot be entered again while it is still running unless your handler is doing something to pump the message queue for new messages.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: in between the two breakpoints, exceptions can still be raised and catch. This approach simply tells the debugger to ignore them instead of stopping the code and prompting the user what to do with them.

Comment: But the question did not ask to do that. It asked to ignore a specific exception class: `EIntOverflow`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, this approach does not allow you to control which specific exceptions to make the debugger ignore. But if you isolate the breakpoints to the smallest possible code block, you reduce the likelihood of other exceptions occurring. On the other hand, in this situation, when formatting a value and the formatting fails for any reason other than an integer overflow, don't you think the debugger should ignore those cases, too? Especially since the `except` is not catching specific exceptions to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a programmatic way (compile-time or run-time) of telling the IDE to locally ignore an exception class, for those occasions when an exception can occur, and you already know that and are handling it?

No.

There's no way for you to ask the debugger to ignore certain `EIntOverflow` exceptions but not others. You either ignore them all, or none of them. The only way you can control which exceptions break in the debugger is through the exception class. You cannot ask the debugger to ignore exceptions in one part of the program, but not another.

Frankly, it seems to me that the right way to tackle this is to work out why you are triggering these exceptions in the first place. And do something to prevent them from occurring at all. The exceptions are symptomatic of a bug in your code which you need to tackle head on.

Comment: Some confusion here.  What I want is some way to disable the debugger's interception of the `EIntOverflow` exception (say) at the start of my FormatDateTimeEx routine, then allow it again on exit from the routine. A bit like the debugger exception version of `{$I-}` and `{$I+}`.  Sure, the best thing to do is stop them from happening, but that may not be easy, or quick to work out.  And if there was a way of doing this, there are probably other exceptions where it might be useful to be able to do this (like Indy for example).

Comment: I'm not sure where the confusion is. You debugger can be configured to ignore certain exception classes. But that config is global. It cannot be applied to local parts of your code. It's all or nothing.

Comment: In [Rob Kennedy's article](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exception-messages) he describes the use of the IDE advanced breakpoints to do this more or less (you can only disable/re-enable all exceptions).  The main disadvantage is that you have to set the breakpoints up in each project the unit is used in.  And it presumably slows down execution.

Comment: @ross Do it that way if you like. I find it surprising that you don't seem inclined to fix the bug in your code.

Comment: I was more interested in the technique than fixing FormatDateTime. If I can ever trigger it reliably again I'll investigate further. Don't you find occasions where you know that an exception can occur in your code at a certain place, you handle it with a `try..except`, and you don't want the debugger to report it, but you _do_ want (unhandled) occurrences of the same exception elsewhere to trigger the debugger?

Comment: Yep. Usually I organise my exception classes in a way that I can filter them globally. Only FastMM debug AVS burn me. Ask yourself what happens with this advanced breakpoints method when there are multiple threads.

Answer (score 3):

You can't control debugger exception handling but you can control compiler options which lead to some of these exceptions.
Here's how you can locally disable compiler switch and then return to it previous state:

1) Initialization - somewhere in the start of a unit or maybe in separate *.inc file.

```
{$IFOPT R+}
  {$DEFINE RangeCheckOn}
{$ENDIF}
```

Here you save the initial (i.e. being set in project settings) state of a compiler switch.
2) Now, the usage:

```
{$R-}
  ...your code here with disabled switch...
{$IFDEF RangeCheckOn}
  {$R+}
{$ENDIF}
```

Here you disable the switch, execute some code without it and return it to initial state when you're done.

I'm using this trick for doing some bit shift operations over (U)Int64 which raise wrong EIntOverflow exception when touching the MSB (compiler bug that is actual for XE2, not sure for newer versions).

But I agree with previous answers that you should check the real reason of the exception being raised. I'd advice you to use your FormatEx version where parameter values would be logged in case of exception. Thus you may track the values that cause exception and check if it's a reproducible case.

Comment: This is all true but seems unrelated to the question at hand. Unless of course you are proposing recompiling the RTL. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Well, AFAIK, EIntOverflow is raised only when $R is set so the issue that topic starter describes could be somewhat solved by using my method over the places of code that raise this exception (i.e., calls to Format). The wrapping could even be added only when running under IDE. Anyway I still insist on using this "try %do something% except {ahh, error? To hell with it} end" approach ONLY if one completely understands what he's doing.

Comment: The user isn't in control of the code that raises the exception. That's already compiled into the RTL. So you are advocating re-compiling the RTL, at least that part of it which applies here.

Comment: Well, code that raises the exception is FormatDateTime which is called directly by him. He's free to wrap it like he did with FormatDateTimeEx.

Comment: No amount of wrapping is going to stop `FormatDateTime` from raising the exception in the first place.

Comment: @David, oh, I see your point. You're right. If we're using Debug RTL it obviously won't be recompiled.

Comment: Well, there's a special batch file {XE}\source\rtl\buildrtl.bat as well as project file to quickly rebuild the whole RTL. So it won't be a big deal as long as all of your components/libs have sources.

Comment: Yeah, you could do that. I would not though.